# Starting C#-ConsoleApp with Parameters in Windows 10

Tags: c#, console-application

I have published a ConsoleApp with VS2017 under Win10 which needs 3 Arguments on starting. I have done the setup.exe and copied the Programm-File (Con_trackTrace1.appref-ms) to C:. In CMD I tried to call it with the Parameters in different ways:

```
Con_trackTrace1.appref-ms argument1 argument2 argument3

Con_trackTrace1.appref-ms -argument1 -argument2 -argument3

Con_trackTrace1 argument1 argument2 argument3

Con_trackTrace1 -argument1 -argument2 -argument3
```

Getting:

> Program not found OR Argument-Index out of Range.

Can someone tell what I´m doing wrong? In Debugging call it with CommandLine-Arguments within the Debug-Options and is running okay.

Here is the Part of taking Arguments:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Parameter setup-Datei
    // Client_ID + Client_SECRET aus textdatei holen (1. Zeile = ClientID, 2. Zeile = ClientSECRET, 3. Zeile = pfad)
    // Zugangsdaten an QA oder PROD anpassen (2 Setup-Dateien)
    string[] setupDatei = null;
    if (args[0] == "prod")
    {
        setupDatei = File.ReadAllLines("C://tracker/setupPROD.txt");
    }
    if (args[0] == "qa")
    {
        setupDatei = File.ReadAllLines("C://tracker/setupQA.txt");
    }

    string clientID = setupDatei[0];
    string clientSECRET = setupDatei[1];
    string pfad = setupDatei[2];
    // Parameter Programmaufruf
    // 1. Umgebung
    string umgebung = args[0];
    // 2. Funktion
    string funktionID = args[1];
    // 3. JSON-Datei (Dateiname OHNE Endung / MUSS .json sein !!!)
    string jsonDateiname = args[2];
}
```

Comment: Is the directory your exe resides in contained in the `PATH` environment variable? Otherwise you should include it in your commandline.

Comment: Okay, that sounds like you're not giving it enough parameters.  Check the length of `args` before you do anything with it.

Comment: @Fildor - I don't even know where to start with what's wrong with your comment.  Sorry, but that is literally nonsense.  Accessing `C:` has nothing to do with the application location.

Comment: Sorry, it's my first ConsoleApp-Publish. I don't know where the .exe really is, only found that .appref-ms File after setup.

Comment: @Fildor - That has nothing to do with putting it in any variation of the Program Files folders.  OP didn't say a folder - just a drive, so telling them to put the application *anywhere* is pointless as you don't know where it currently is and what folder they were trying to run it from.  It's not helpful.

Comment: @comidos The appref-ms file is for installing your application, not executing it.  Do you just want to run the application from the command line?

Comment: @Fildor - Sorry, but nothing in what they said gives reason for your incorrect suggestion.  You should really ask for clarification before giving advice as it will most likely add to the problem and make it worse.

Comment: @comidos Can you please tell us where _exactly_ your exe is residing and what folder you are in in cmd when calling it?

Comment: @Archer: Ah okay, i thought this is the starting-file because the ProgramFolder-Entry of Windows is pointing to that file.

Comment: @Archer: Deinstalled. I copied all stuff from the bin/Debug/app.publish-Folder of the Solution into c:/track. tried to start exe of program there. Error cause of missing DLL. Started setup.exe in this folder and tried again to start Program-exe. Still missing the DLL

Comment: If you just want to run the executable then you can get it from your bin\debug folder (or release folder, if you've built from a release config).  Just copy it to wherever you want, or run it from there.  Just make sure that when you have your command prompt you're in the correct folder (shift & right-click in Explorer gives you the option to "Open command window here")

Comment: You'll need the DLLs from the debug folder as well.  The EXE relies on them so they must be copied as well.  Make sure they're all in the same folder and it should be fine.

Comment: @Archer Thank you for that Basic-Knowledge!

Comment: No problem - happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Summary of the Basic Stuff i have learned:

Installing with setup.exe is not needed. Copying all files from the bin/Release-Folder of VS-Solution-Folder to Destination-Folder and start the Program-Exe there with Arguments.

All needed DLLs have to be in the Folder of the Exe-File.

Thanks a lot to ARCHER